# Button Location based on random number - xCode 6 (swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to make a button move to 5 different locations depending on a random number (1-6), I also want to display they random number in a label.

I have written the following code but the button doesn't seem to move to the location I specified in the IF statement: -

```
import UIKit

class game: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Decalare display label
    @IBOutlet var d1: UILabel!  

    //One Button declaration
    @IBOutlet var oneBTN: UIButton!

    @IBAction func rollBTNPress(sender: AnyObject) {

        //Generate random number
        var r = arc4random_uniform(5)

    //Display dice1 number in d1 Label
        d1.text = "\(dice1)"


        if (r == 1) {
            oneBTN.center = CGPointMake(10, 70);
        } else if (r == 2) {
            oneBTN.center = CGPointMake(30, 70);
        } else if (r == 3) {
            oneBTN.center = CGPointMake(50, 70);
        } else if (r == 4) {
            oneBTN.center = CGPointMake(70, 70);
        } else if (r == 5) {
            oneBTN.center = CGPointMake(90, 70);
        } else {
            oneBTN.center = CGPointMake(0, 70);
        }

    }

}
```

The code runs and compiles without any issues. However the button position seems to be random and it's actually ignoring the coordinates specified in the IF statement.

What's even stranger is that if I comment out the `d1.text = "\(dice1)"` the button begins to move in the correct positions depending on the random number.

I also tried to change the CGPointMake and use CGPoint instead but I get exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Autolayout is changing the location of your button.  See the discussion at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227093/swift-nstimer-and-iboutlet-issue/26227531#26227531

Comment: That's awesome, so simple and yet wasted so much of my time! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to vacawama for answering this question in the comments, indeed disabling Autolayout solved the issue.

More detailed answer here: -

[Swift NSTimer and IBOutlet Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227093/swift-nstimer-and-iboutlet-issue/26227531#26227531)

Answer (score -1):

```
@IBAction func moveButton(button: UIButton) {
    // Find the button's width and height
    let buttonWidth = button.frame.width
    let buttonHeight = button.frame.height

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let viewWidth = button.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = button.superview!.bounds.height

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
    button.center.x = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
    button.center.y = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation on how your solution works for OP